# How can I write in a comprehension list beggining by the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello I have this code using Python :

```
a = [x for x in range(0,10)]
a = a[::-1]
```

But I would like to write these lines above in one line  I mean I would like to begin to have something like this :

at the beginning :

```
a[0] = 9
```

then

```
a[0] = 8
a[1] = 9
```

...

and finally

```
a[0] = 0
```

...

```
a[9] = 9
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I mean I have a loop for and I want to have a comprehension list to increase the speed, but in my loop for I began by the end of the list

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
a = [x for x in range(9,-1,-1)][::-1]
```

Comment: sorry but when I try a[0] I got 9 instead of 0

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Ok it is perfect  there was no the [::-1] ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [x for x in range(9,-1,-1)]
print(a)

a = [x for x in range(0,10,1)][::-1]
print(a)
```